# Track user-agents that visit a site

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a website and I want to track all user-agents that visit it. And save all the user-agents on a file, or send by email. How can I achieve that in PHP or JS?

Comment: well if the site is running on Apache, Apache does it for you by default. they are stored in the access log. another option is goggle analytics

Comment: echo $SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

Comment: In javascript its "navigator.userAgent;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, three things need to happen. Write the file, mail the contents and clear the file after mailing. the first part will be in a separate file, whilst the mail and file clearing will be in another file

```
<?php

    // get the user agent
    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    // write to file
    file_put_contents( 'user_agents.log', $user_agent, FILE_APPEND );

?>

<?php


    // fetch the list of user agents from the file
    $body = file_get_contents( 'user_agents.log' );

    // mail to whereva
    mail( 'admin@example.com', 'User Agent Log', $body );

    // truncate the file back to zero
    $fh = fopen( 'user_agents.log', 'w' );
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For PHP you can use: https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-php
and append each detected user-agent to txt file via php:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use UAParser\Parser;

$ua = $SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

$parser = Parser::create();
$result = $parser->parse($ua);

$fp = fopen('user-agents.txt', 'a'); //opens file in append mode  
fwrite($fp, $result->ua->toString());  
fclose($fp);
```

Note, using the library gives you many options to receive wanted data from user-agent.
For example for user-agent '*Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Ma...*' you can achieve that data:

```
print $result->ua->family;            // Safari
print $result->ua->major;             // 6
print $result->ua->minor;             // 0
print $result->ua->patch;             // 2
print $result->ua->toString();        // Safari 6.0.2
print $result->ua->toVersion();       // 6.0.2

print $result->os->family;            // Mac OS X
print $result->os->major;             // 10
print $result->os->minor;             // 7
print $result->os->patch;             // 5
print $result->os->patchMinor;        // [null]
print $result->os->toString();        // Mac OS X 10.7.5
print $result->os->toVersion();       // 10.7.5

print $result->device->family;        // Other

print $result->toString();            // Safari 6.0.2/Mac OS X 10.7.5
print $result->originalUserAgent;     // Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Ma...
```

Comment: link only answers are discouraged

Comment: Yes, you are right. I edited my answer to complete solution.

Comment: looks interesting, but i would use the webserver log file, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yes, but if you want to extract specified data form user-agents I think that package could be helpful.